# Port 53 on my home router opened, why?

Tags: dns, router, lan

I couldn't find anything online so I'm here to ask experts. I've nmapped my public ip and I noticed all ports are closed but the 53. In the router's options upnp is disabled and the NAT rules are empty. Could it be a malware using dns for comunication?
Also how can I close it?

Comment: Did you nmap your router's public IP from the WAN side of your router, or from the LAN side?

Answer (score 2):

Most home WiFi routers/access points contain a forwarding DNS server to serve locally conntected clients. You can change the router DHCP settings to provide e.g. Google's DNS servers and disable/firewall the built-in DNS server.